# How to fix "Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type."?

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript, I have a `lang` variable declared as something returned as a string type value, and a `direction` variable declared as an object of two elements, now I have a function that needs to return the value of `direction` object based on the `lang` value, but there is an error for `lang` of `direction[lang]` which says `null' cannot be used as an index type.`, I just know that the `lang` will never be null, anyone knows how I can fix this problem?

```
export const lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') ? localStorage.getItem('lang') : "en";

export const direction  = {
    ru: "rtl",
    en: "ltr"
}

function getDirection() {
    return direction[lang];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the determined type of constant `lang` is `string|null`. The compiler determines that if `localStorage.getItem('lang')` is null then the first if-branch is hit and since the signature of `localStorage.getItem` returns null then the `lang` can be null. If the second if-branch is hit then the `lang` can be a `string` as well, hence the type `string | null`. The compiler isn't smart enough to figure out that `getItem` is called with the same argument and to infer that the data type of `lang` can only be string.

That being said, this should work fine:

```
export const lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') ?? "en";
export const direction:any  = {
    ru: "rtl",
    en: "ltr"
}

export function getDirection() {
    return direction[lang];
}
```